# How to use Struts url tag in iterator tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator

Please see following code:

```
<s:iterator value="managers" status="counter" var="manager">
  <tr>
    <td><s:property value="#counter.count" /></td> 
    <td><s:property value="nickname"/></td>
    <td><s:property value="username"/></td>
    <s:url value="/admin/retrieve?action=edit&id=" var="edit" />
    <td><s:a href="%{edit}">Edit</s:a></td>
    <s:url value="/admin/retrieve?action=remove&id=" var="remove" />
    <td><s:a href="%{remove}">Remove</s:a></td>
  </tr> 
</s:iterator>
```

I have 2 links in this iterator. This code iterate on `ArrayList<Manager>` that contains `username`, `nickname`, `password`, `id`. 
How can I add manager id in the end of link. Link will be similar to this:
`/admin/retrieve?action=remove&id=2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<s:url value="/admin/retrieve?action=remove&id=%{id}" var="remove" />
```

the `Manager` should have `getId()` method.